# How to fix "Error in (function...) arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, matrix, satellite-image

I am trying to summarize the values of a raster of a satellite image of NDVI values. I have already extracted the data and it seem to have populated a list that I can see in the console window, but I cannot see it using the "view" function, nor can I make it into a .csv.

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))
ndvi <- stack(r, r*2, r*3)
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-160,5), c(-60, 0), c(-160,-60), c(-180,-20))
cds2 <- rbind(c(80,0), c(100,60), c(120,0), c(120,-55), c(80,0))
polys <- spPolygons(cds1, cds2)
```

Extract values

```
v <- extract(ndvi, polys)
```

Write to file

```
write.csv(v, "test.csv")
#Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 38, 23

str(v)
#List of 2
# $ : num [1:38, 1:3] 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 ...
#  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. ..$ : NULL
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "layer.1" "layer.2" "layer.3"
# $ : num [1:23, 1:3] 173 208 209 244 245 280 281 282 315 316 ...
#  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. ..$ : NULL
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "layer.1" "layer.2" "layer.3"
```

I expect to be able to at some point do a correlation of this with another set of data using the distribution of the cell values of the NDVI imagery, so in order to do that I need to have a working csv of all of the values of the cells. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please try to make your code reproducible, by including the packages that you use via `library(packagename)`  and show the actual error message, and where it occurs. Do not show code that is (apparently) irrelevant to your question such as `temp@legend@colortable`

Comment: Updated, and added the function used to download the data which seems necessary as well

Comment: I changed the example to make it *general, simple, and reproducible*

Answer (score 0):

We have no idea what object type `vals_03_01` is because you provide no information on the `shp` object. Depending on the input(s) from raster and sp, the outputs can be quite different. If the spatial-vector object contains polygons then `vals_03_01` will be a list. If `shp` are points then extract will return a vector (for a single raster) or matrix (for stack/brick where columns represent each raster in the stack).

Please look at the class, dimensions and structure of the `vals_03_01` object using `class`, `dim` and `str`. This will tell you if your data is appropriate to write the results directly to a flat file or need additional processing/summary (eg., `lapply`) before export. It very well could be that `extract` returned a list containing matrix objects.

Comment: I just updated my problem statement with answers to these questions, basically the shapefile "shp" is made up of polygons which means "vals_03_01" is returned as a list, and dim(vals_03_01) returns "NULL" Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`v` is a list. Each element of the list has the raster cell values that are covered by a polygon. The number of cells varies by polygon, so you cannot turn this into a rectangular matrix.

That means that you cannot use `write.csv` or `View`.

Do you need a "csv" file anyway (how do you need a certain file type to do a correlation)? You can do `saveRDS(v, "test.rds")` instead.

Perhaps you want a single value for each polygon? 
In that case, you can do:

```
v <- extract(ndvi, polys, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
v
#      layer.1  layer.2   layer.3
#[1,] 387.8158 775.6316 1163.4474
#[2,] 329.3913 658.7826  988.1739

write.csv(v, "test.csv")
```

See `?raster::extract`